# getting error while rendering contact form and header title from database together in django

Tags: django, database, jinja2, contact-form

in `forms.py`, i want to render data to my database together with a contact form attached but when i try to do that it gives an html page instead of my index template

```py
def home(request):
    base = BaseHeader.objects.all()
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = contactForm()
    else:
        form = contactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            Phonenumber = form.cleaned_data['Phonenumber']
            try:
                send_mail(
                    'Subject here',
                    'Here is the message.',
                    'from@gmail.com',
                    ['to@gmail.com'],
                    fail_silently=False,)
               
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            return redirect('home')
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form},{'menu_titles': base})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you've made an error in `return` statement, you are passing `context`, the 3rd parameter,  to the `render` function the wrong way, it should be like following:

```py
def home(request):

    [..]
    

    context = {
        'form': form,
        'menu_titles': base
    }
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial03/#a-shortcut-render

#### Note

django expects `forms.py` and NOT `form.py` to hold all Form classes (i already updated your question)